# mysql bind param needs a persistent(from bind to execution) object?

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement, bind, param

when i use prepared statement, i see mysql takes a pointer to MYSQL_BIND.buffer

For example, to bind an integer i need to provide the pointer to integer rather than integer itself. 
Does it mean that the integer address should be accessible until the query ends?

It would be convenient to bind a temporary object and then execute it later but since it takes a pointer 
I'm wondering if I can do that.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on experiment,

Yes I indeed needed live object for bind parameter until mysql completes the query.